# PHP Json array decode in php and inserting mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
"SCI-6":{"quantity":11,"id":"SCI-6","price":15,"name":"notebooks"},
"SCI-7":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-7","price":10,"name":"posters"},
"SCI-8":{"quantity":2,"id":"SCI-8","price":15,"name":"pen"},
"SCI-9":{"quantity":4,"id":"SCI-9","price":100,"name":"charger"},
"SCI-10":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-10","price":10.25,"name":"News Paper"}
```

please help me to decode as variables and insert the values to Mysql using php

Comment: use php json_decode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = '{"SCI-6":{"quantity":11,"id":"SCI-6","price":15,"name":"notebooks"},"SCI-7":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-7","price":10,"name":"posters"},"SCI-8":{"quantity":2,"id":"SCI-8","price":15,"name":"pen"},"SCI-9":{"quantity":4,"id":"SCI-9","price":100,"name":"charger"},"SCI-10":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-10","price":10.25,"name":"News Paper"}}';

$json_data=json_decode($data);
foreach($json_data as $json_value)
{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO yourtable (quantity, id, price, name) values ('".$json_value->quantity."','".$json_value->id."','".$json_value->price."','".$json_value->name."')");

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `json_decode` — Decodes a JSON string

Try as below :

```
<?php 
$json = '{"SCI-6":{"quantity":11,"id":"SCI-6","price":15,"name":"notebooks"},"SCI-7":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-7","price":10,"name":"posters"},"SCI-8":{"quantity":2,"id":"SCI-8","price":15,"name":"pen"},"SCI-9":{"quantity":4,"id":"SCI-9","price":100,"name":"charger"},"SCI-10":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-10","price":10.25,"name":"News Paper"}}';
$result_data = json_decode($json);
foreach($result_data as $value)
{
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare("INSERT INTO tablename (quantity, id, price, name) (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "dsss", $value->quantity, $value->id, $value->price, $value->name);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
?>
```

Output you will get is :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [SCI-6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quantity] => 11
            [id] => SCI-6
            [price] => 15
            [name] => notebooks
        )

    [SCI-7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quantity] => 1
            [id] => SCI-7
            [price] => 10
            [name] => posters
        )

    [SCI-8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quantity] => 2
            [id] => SCI-8
            [price] => 15
            [name] => pen
        )

    [SCI-9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quantity] => 4
            [id] => SCI-9
            [price] => 100
            [name] => charger
        )

    [SCI-10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quantity] => 1
            [id] => SCI-10
            [price] => 10.25
            [name] => News Paper
        )

)
```

Comment: i'm just wondering how can he access an object inside..  `$obj->SCI-6->quantity` will make it asystax error?

Comment: @roullie `foreach` loop will solve the problem. Please look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your json string is

```
$dat = '{"SCI-6":{"quantity":11,"id":"SCI-6","price":15,"name":"notebooks"},"SCI-7":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-7","price":10,"name":"posters"},"SCI-8":{"quantity":2,"id":"SCI-8","price":15,"name":"pen"},"SCI-9":{"quantity":4,"id":"SCI-9","price":100,"name":"charger"},"SCI-10":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-10","price":10.25,"name":"News Paper"}}';
```

With the opening and closing brackets at the end (otherwise it's not valid json) then we can decode it like the following:

```
$jsondata = json_decode($dat, true);
foreach($jsondata as $vals)
{
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare("INSERT INTO yourtable (quantity, id, price, name) (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "dsss", $vals['quantity'], $vals['id'], $vals['price'], $vals['name']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_decode function for decoding json:

```
$string = '{"SCI-6":{"quantity":11,"id":"SCI-6","price":15,"name":"notebooks"},"SCI-7":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-7","price":10,"name":"posters"},"SCI-8":{"quantity":2,"id":"SCI-8","price":15,"name":"pen"},"SCI-9":{"quantity":4,"id":"SCI-9","price":100,"name":"charger"},"SCI-10":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-10","price":10.25,"name":"News Paper"}}';

echo "<pre>";    
print_r(json_decode($string));
```

**Result:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [SCI-6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quantity] => 11
            [id] => SCI-6
            [price] => 15
            [name] => notebooks
        )

    [SCI-7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quantity] => 1
            [id] => SCI-7
            [price] => 10
            [name] => posters
        )

    [SCI-8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quantity] => 2
            [id] => SCI-8
            [price] => 15
            [name] => pen
        )

    [SCI-9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quantity] => 4
            [id] => SCI-9
            [price] => 100
            [name] => charger
        )

    [SCI-10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quantity] => 1
            [id] => SCI-10
            [price] => 10.25
            [name] => News Paper
        )

)
```

**Side Note:**

Your `json` consists on multidimensional array so you need to use `json` inside the `{}`.

Comment: @AbhilashEnair: u r welcome, dont forget to chose the best answer as accepted..

Answer (score -1):

You can use `json_decode()` to decode the json data.

You can also try `unserialize()` if it doesn't works.